# FFmpeg.execute.FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

My Code:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           execFFmpegBinary( " -i" + newFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -pass 2 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 " + dest1.getAbsolutePath());

       }
   });


public void execFFmpegBinary(final String command) {
    try {
        Log.d("path....",command);
        ffmpeg.execute( command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : "+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg "+command);
                Log.d(TAG, "progress : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
```

Show this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mypc.videocut, PID: 26910
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg.execute(java.lang.String, com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` is currently not instancied

You must call first:

```
ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
```

And try to load library:

```
try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                Log.e(TAG,"");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"");
    }
```

So after that you can use `execute` method

Answer (score 0):

parameter in method `execFFmpegBinary` has to be `String[]` not `String`...